# Creating functions, adding argument to range

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments, range

I am brand new at programming (just learned what a command line is); no previous experience and just found this website so excuse any formatting errors.

I am really struggling with adding arguments to a function. Specifically, I need to add an argument to a function I created in which I am returning a range with increments of 5. For reasons that are beyond my current skill level (but obvious to you guys, I'm sure), I cannot use the main function to replace the 51 in my fname function with 101. Essentially, I have to give fname an argument for the upper-end of the range. From the main function, I have to pass the value of 101 to the fname function so that fname returns [0, 5, 10, ... , 100] to the main function and the main function prints this to the screen.

```
def fname(arg1):
    """this function will compute a range from 0 to 50 in increments of 5"""
    result = list(range(0, 51, 5))
    return result


def main():
    arg1 = list(range(0, 101, 5))
    from_fname_function = fname(arg1)
    print(from_fname_function)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help (with thorough explanation) would be greatly appreciated. I have found many resources with how to use arguments in a function, but I cannot figure out how to change the max limit in the range in this way.

Comment: Why not just pass `101` to `fname(arg1)` and change `51` to `arg1`?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial resource.  Please work through tutorials on the appropriate topics; post again when your question is more focused.

Comment: The main page (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) states this website is for "Ask[ing] [questions] about...specific programming problems, software algorithms, coding techniques, [and] software development tools." It also says "[do not ask] Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)" I thought my question met these standards, but if not I do apologize for my confusion. I am very grateful for those who commented offering help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you are not using the argument you have added in the function body. Judging from the docstring, I assume you want to make the upper boundary of the range flexible. Try sth along the following lines:

```
def fname(arg1):
    # actually use the argument to build the range
    result = list(range(0, arg1, 5))  
    return result

def main():
    arg1 = 101
    from_fname_function = fname(arg1)
    print(from_fname_function)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. When I substituted your suggestion but kept the if/main statement at the bottom, it gave an error that mentioned something about "maximum recursion depth" (wish I would have copied the entire error message; I cannot seem to make it happen again). I was told that the if/main statement helps a function be called/imported without automatically running it. Why would the if/main then cause output to be reiterated? (Not the original question and if needed to be asked elsewhere I apologize).

Comment: What you were told is correct =) From the given code it is also unrelated to the error since it has little to do with recursion.  One would need to see the full code of what triggered the error to say more.

Answer (score 0):

I think the trick you are looking for is to have the function `fname` to be able to return lists that start at zero and go in increments of 5, up to whatever limit you choose. You are really close; you just need to use the parameter `arg1` when you make the range, like this:

```
def fname(arg):
    return list(range(0, arg, 5))
```

Now you can *use* the function to make lots of different lists:

```
def main():
    print(fname(51))      # this will print [0, 5, 10, ..., 50]
    print(fname(101))     # this will print [0, 5, 10, ..., 100]
    print(fname(10))      # this will print [0, 5]
```

The idea of function arguments is that they allow you to make a function that can do something with different values at different times. So if you want to make lists starting at zero that have increments of five, and you want to do this for different ending values, then you make the limit be the argument (because that's the part that changes), and use the argument at just the right place in the function.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
def fname(start, end, inc):
    return list(range(start, end, inc))

print(fname(0,51,5))
```

In the above code the function fname returns the list of values from 'start' to 'end' with the increment 'inc'

op:
[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]